# No Database Selected in Num_Rows

Tags: php, mysql, database, rows

Got a strange error saying that I'm not connected to a database while running a mysqli_num_rows query.  Here is the code:

```
    <?php include("php/functions.php"); ?>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['verification']) && !empty($_GET['verification'])){  
    // Verify data  
    $hash = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['verification']); // Set hash variable  

    $search_sql = "SELECT 'hash', active FROM members WHERE hash='".$verification."' AND active='0'";   
    $search_res = mysqli_query($con, $search_sql);
    $match = mysqli_num_rows($search_res);
```

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: what your $con contains?

Comment: Why you closing your php tag ? When code seems continue in php.

Comment: share functions.php file

Comment: Sorry, that's outside of this code, but used it to show there's a connection included

Comment: Just add include("functions.php"); // you forgot to add php extension her.

Comment: My connection us $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","database"); but I know this is working as it has been fine on all other pages of the site

Comment: Your file extension is wrong. See my answer below.

Comment: I've added the full code (up to a point)

Comment: In your `SELECT` statement remove the single quotes around the column names and use back ticks `\`\`` instead.

Comment: @Asok Thanks but that didn't work either - really strange that this isn't working

Comment: run a `var_dump($con)` and make sure that you are passing the value you think you are passing as the connection... Something must have gone awry there somewhere.

Comment: paste the code for functions.php also

Answer (score 1):

I have changed several things in your code, please review.

If you are using the `mysqli` class then anything after your class instatiation should look something like:

```
$con = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
$con->exampleClassFunction()
```

using the object operator `->`.

To get the `num_rows` your object operator would be after the query variable, like so:

```
$search_res = $con->mysqli_query($con, $search_sql);
$match = $search_res->mysqli_num_rows($search_res);
```

I also added the backticks to all applicable column names in your query:

```
SELECT `hash`, `active` FROM members WHERE `hash`='".$verification."' AND `active`='0'
```

Here is an example with your code:

```
//include("php/functions.php");

$DB_NAME = 'DATABASE_NAME';
$DB_HOST = 'DATABASE_HOST';
$DB_USER = 'DATABASE_USER';
$DB_PASS = 'DATABASE_PASSWORD';

$con = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);

// Added a connection error check before continuing
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if(isset($_GET['verification']) && !empty($_GET['verification'])){  
    $hash = $con->mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['verification']);

    // Use back ticks on query column names, 
    // use single quotes for comparative operations
    $search_sql = "SELECT `hash`, `active` FROM members WHERE `hash` = '".$verification."' AND `active` = '0'";

    $search_res = $con->mysqli_query($con, $search_sql);
    $match = $search_res->mysqli_num_rows($search_res);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<?php include('functions.php'); ?>`

Also, make sure you have your closing `?>` tag in the correct place.

Answer (score 0):

just try to make it include("functions.php")..
I think thats your problem

Comment: Sorry, ignore the include file extenstion

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    include("functions.php"); //includes databse connection
    $search_sql = "SELECT hash, active FROM members WHERE hash='".$verification."' AND active='0'";   
    $search_res = mysqli_query($con, $search_sql);
    $match      = mysqli_num_rows($search_res);
?>
```

`include("functions");` or `include("functions.php");` ??? You forgot `.php`

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add file extension.

```
<?php include("functions.php"); ?>
```

also put `

around `hash` as its reserved word by `MySQL`.

Answer (score 0):

please try the below code:

```
<?php 
    include("functions.php"); //includes databse connection php file
    $search_sql = "SELECT hash, active FROM members WHERE hash='".$verification."' AND active='0'";   
    $search_res = mysqli_query($con, $search_sql);
    $match      = mysqli_num_rows($search_res);
?>
```

include should have a .php file as parameter. please check it.

Comment: No that wasn't an error - I've edited my question and added the complete code - I know that the functions php is working